# socket io room authorization for listeners

Tags: node.js, socket.io

suppose I have an room_id and I am registering my users to it.

```
let room_id = "2133"

socket.join(room_id, function() {
                socket.emit(room_id, { message: `application joined: ${room_id}` })
     });
```

and this works fine. but listening to this room is open for everyone.

if u**ser=admin1** registers to **room_id="2133"**, the **user="james"** can listen to the  room_id="2133" and get all the traffics.

how to add authorize lvl to room?

Comment: If you wanna emit something to this room online you can use `io.in(room_id).emit('your events', data);`. I'm not sure if you can really authorize someone to a room specificly =?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confused about the definition of room and namespace.
joining the clients only can be done on the server-side.

as **@Halil Çakar** said in the comment, you can emit messages directly to rooms with  **event namespace**.

```
io.in(room_id).emit('your events', data)
```